# Get Index of number in reverse direction of a string - PLSQL

Tags: regex, string, oracle, plsql

How to find out the index of the first number encountered in the reverse direction of a string?

For example: 'CUSTOMC23VBA' and 'CUSTOMC245BA'.

So, function should return as '2' or '3' from reverse or the index value as '9' or '10'.

I could get the value by hard-coding the SUBSTR('CUSTOMC23VBA', -3) but I would want it to be generic as regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select regexp_instr(reverse('CUSTOM123XYZ'), '[[:digit:]]',1,1) from dual
```

Output: 4

Zero based index would be:

```
select regexp_instr(reverse('CUSTOM123XYZ'), '[[:digit:]]',1,1)-1 from dual
```

Output: 3

If you want the rest of the string from the last number, you can use substr and take advantage of the negative position to count from end of string:

```
select substr('CUSTOM123XYZ', -1 * (regexp_instr(reverse('CUSTOM123XYZ'), '[[:digit:]]',1,1)-1)) from dual;
```

Output: XYZ

An example testing multiple input strings:

```
with d as (
select 'CUSTOM123XYZ' as input_str from dual
union
select 'CUSTOM123XZ' as input_str from dual
union
select 'CUSTOM 1 X 3YZ' as input_str from dual
)
select input_str, 
    substr(input_str, -1 * (regexp_instr(reverse(input_str), '[[:digit:]]',1,1)-1)) as result
from d
```

Output:

```
INPUT_STR           RESULT
CUSTOM 1 X 3YZ      YZ
CUSTOM123XYZ        XYZ
CUSTOM123XZ         XZ
```

Comment: Great. It works..Is there any way we can modify to get the remaining string from the index of the first encountered number please?

Comment: thats it, its just not 0 based (1=>Z, 2=>Y, 3=>X, 4=>4).  If you want zero based index, just substract 1.  See edits above

Comment: oh, ok.  So you want the output to be "XYZ" in this case?  Or "21MOTSUC"?  Or "CUSTOM12"?

Comment: You were too quick.. sorry for the latest updates.. I would need "XYZ"

Comment: Accepting the answer, as the Output XYZ works but the same query is not working if I just have XZ.

Comment: you have to change BOTH places if you change the input string

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one number in the string? if so, you could go for something like this:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('CUSTOMC23VBA', '[[:alpha:]]','')  from dual
```

But this will fail when there are multiple numbers in the string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have multiple numbers